# Scroller's background at NSTableView

Tags: xcode, macos, nstableview, nsscrollview, nsscroller

How can I change background color of scroller at NSTableView? For example I've made black background color of my TableView and got white scroller, I want ClearColor or Black color of Scroller's background. How can I make it?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to subclass `NSScroller` and override its `-(void)drawRect:` method

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // the only line is required
    [self drawKnob];
}
```

Comment: That answer have one issue. If knob is not needed to be displayed (e.g. tableView has only 1 row) your function displays knob. It's any way to check if knob is needed to be displayed and than call `drawKnob`?

Comment: Couldn't find any easy solution. You should add property isVisible (`if (self.isVisible) [drawKnob];`) and set its value somewhere in  your `NSTableView` class according to contents height.

Comment: It's really so strange that Apple uses transparent knobs in native applications but there is no simple solution in XCode

Comment: Knobs started being opaque since El Capitan if I'm not mistaken.